# Can't import some existing modules in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web

I'm using Python on my web server (which is Heliohost) and I'm unable to import some Python modules. Whenever I try to import them, I get a `500 internal server error`.

The modules I'm not able to import are `numpy` and `tensorflow`, which should be installed because running the script below that should print all the installed modules

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import cgitb
import pip
print("Content-Type: text/html")
cgitb.enable(format='text')
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
```

returns a lot of Python modules, with `tensorflow` and `numpy` as well.

Basically, the scripts work fine with any other Python module, it gives an error only with those two.

What could be the problem? Unfortunately, I can't access the server logs because my web server provider doesn't allow it, and with `cgitb` enabled (that should print any error in the code), it just returns the `error 500` without printing anything else.

Comment: You could use logging and `try/except` together with `logging.error()` to see if you can gather a bit more info on what is going on?

Comment: Thanks for the aswer, i tried what you suggested but still got the 500 error, without any log printed. However, i tried to go deeper to find the error, finding out that the tensorflow folder is inside the sys.path, so Python should be able to import it without any problem, if i understood correctly what sys.path is (it should be the location where Python searches for the modules, right?)

Comment: Not necessarily. Tensorflow uses natively-compiled Python extension modules, and those have further dependencies; any of those pieces could be missing.

Comment: You'd want to configure the logging module to output to a file log somewhere the CGI process has write access to, and you want to [log the exception in an exception handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception).

Comment: Also, 500 errors are usually logged; do you have access to the HTTP logs anywhere? You may want to check those out.